# Find the condition under which an inequality is satisfied

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities, parameters

I need to find the conditions among the variables under which the inequality `est-tru>0` holds.

```
kldFunc[x_, y_] := x Log[x/y] + (1 - x) Log[(1 - x)/(1 - y)];

pt = μ/n;
tru = Exp[-kldFunc[pt - ϵ, pt] n];

pe = (x + n ϵ)/n;
est = Exp[-kldFunc[pe - ϵ, pe] n]
```

These are the constraints on the variables

```
n > 0 && 1 > ϵ > 0 && n > μ > 0 && n > x > 0 && 
 n > (x + n ϵ) > μ && n ∈ Integers && 
 x ∈ Integers
```

Can Mathematica do this? Which built-in function should I use?

I tried `Reduce`, but it didn't work.

```
Reduce[est - tru >= 0 && n > 0 && 1 > ϵ > 0 && 
  n > μ > 0 && n > x > 0 && n > (x + n ϵ) > μ && 
  n ∈ Integers && x ∈ Integers, {μ, x, 
  n, ϵ}]
(*$ Aborted[] *)
```

Comment: I believe that you must have `Sign[pt-ϵ]==Sign[pt]&&Sign[1-(pt-ϵ)]==Sign[1-pt]&&Sign[pe-ϵ]==Sign[pe]&&Sign[1-(pe-ϵ)]==Sign[1-pe]` or `est>=tru` fails. I am guessing this is why `Reduce` is failing for you. I believe that `n>(x+n ϵ)>μ` may be true or false and `est>=tru` may still be true. I believe that `(pe-ϵ)*Log[(pe-ϵ)/pe]+(1-(pe-ϵ))Log[(1-(pe-ϵ))/(1-pe)] < (pt-ϵ)*Log[(pt-ϵ)/pt]+(1-(pt-ϵ))Log[(1-(pt-ϵ))/(1-pt)]` must be true for `est>=tru` to be true. I am still trying to find a simpler constraint that makes that true, but it is not looking good.

Comment: `n=.;ϵ=.;μ=.;x=.;kldFunc[x_,y_]:=x Log[x/y]+(1-x)Log[(1-x)/(1-y)];While[True, Print["."];n=RandomInteger[{2,10}];x=RandomInteger[{1,n-1}];ϵ=RandomReal[{0,1}]; μ=RandomReal[{0,n}];pt=μ/n;tru=Exp[-kldFunc[pt-ϵ,pt]n];pe=(x+n ϵ)/n;est=Exp[-kldFunc[pe-ϵ,pe]n];If[(pt-ϵ)/pt>0&&(1-(pt-ϵ))/(1-pt)>0&&(pe-ϵ)/pe>0&&(1-(pe-ϵ))/(1-pe)>0&&est>tru,Break[]]];{n,ϵ,μ,x,est,tru,est>=tru}` Positive and negative values and things both inside and outside of `Log` and `Exp` all make it very hard to find a single simple constraint. `Reduce` hasn't found it and `Reduce` is way better than I am.